# Is there a way that I can redirect my page (jsp) to another page (jsp) after an ajax post call in springmvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

Basically my scenario is I am trying to send a list of 3 objects as a string to my controller by using ajax post as shown below.

JavaScript function for AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "ajaxEditFormUpdate",
    data: JSON.stringify(newData),
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
    }
});
```

MyController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajaxEditFormUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView handleResponse(@RequestBody String records) {
        System.out.println(records);
        String viewName = "content/review";
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName(viewName);
        return mav;
    }
```

Here I want my page to be redirected to review(jsp) page, but whats happening in my case is it still retains in the same page but in the response section of the network(in chrome dev tools), I can see my JSP page in html format, but the page is not being rendered. Is there a way that I can render the review page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't go to the page which you recived in the response to the POST request.
But your can add **success** to ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
url: "ajaxEditFormUpdate",
data: JSON.stringify(newData),
beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
},
success: function (response) {
    window.location.href = '/content/review';
}
});
```

You controller now will be looking like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajaxEditFormUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Void> handleResponse(@RequestBody String records) {
        System.out.println(records);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

but now you also need make new controller with GET to return view for `/content/review` page

**p.s.** Another variant seems to be a hack if you still want to render page without changing any controllers, your success must will be like this:

```
success: function (response) {
        document.open();
        document.write(response);
        document.close();
    }
```

But this approach is not recommended.

Comment: Which variant did you prefer: normal or hack?

Comment: normal one, by adding a extra controller to fetch the review page