# redirect with POST request using jquery and SpringMVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring-mvc

I want to redirect a page with only POST request using jquery/Angular1.0 and SpringMVC. I dont want to use GET request for redirection. Can anyone suggest me regarding this issue.

Comment: Please provide more details. See [ask]

Comment: You can't go to the page which you recived in the response to the POST request with redirect. Or make ```window.location.href = '/page';``` after success response or you can change current page content with response. look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542995/is-there-a-way-that-i-can-redirect-my-page-jsp-to-another-page-jsp-after-an/42544392#42544392)